# if True do save data to file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to save data to file after response True in python.

For example

```
a = 1
if a = 1 save to file.txt
```

After callotherfunction i want to get response and check if true save it to a file : example.txt

Any idea!

Best regards.

Comment: so you want to write the data character to a file if it's value is true?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [MCVE]. Right now your code snippet is not even a correct Python (it raises `IndentationError`).

Comment: Even the question ain't very clear!

Comment: I update the question if you can understand me.

Comment: What i want is to check if reponse is true save data to file.txt

Comment: You want either `if a == 1:` (you have only one `=`), or the more Pythonic `if a:`. BTW, the question is still very confusing - what is `callotherfunction`, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but based on what there is, here is an example to get you started:

```
# You stated 'after callotherfunction I want to get response'.
# This is how you call another function and save the response to a variable.
# Ensure you swap out `otherfunction` for the actual function name
result = otherfunction()

# You said you wanted to check if the result is `True` - this will explicitly check that.
# However, your example is using the numeric `1`. 
# If you just want to check for a 'positive' (non zero, non empty, non null), 
# You can just do `if result:`
if result == True:
     # This is one way of opening a file and writing text to it in python 2.7
     # There are other ways for more complicated outputs - e.g. the csv module
     with open('path/to/output/file.txt', 'w') as fout:
         fout.write('...')
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i need. Best regards